# What are the ways to bound function for using the theorem of dominated convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I need to bound $f(x,n)=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1+n\ln(1+x^2)}$, on $(0,1)$. I tried to use the fact that $a^2+b^2\geqslant 2ab$, but integral $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln(1+ x^2)}}\ dx$ is not convergent so I can't use theorem of dominated convergence.

Also I know about analysis methods if a function is convex, but I don't know how to use it.  I know about Jensen's inequality, but I need to know how with this to see if a function is bigger than some function that is integrable.

Comment: Not convergent? $$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \sinh^{-1}(1) = \ln(1+\sqrt{2})$$

Comment: Convergent or not  the sequence of functions is not bounded by the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Comment: I made mistake, I meant $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\ln x^2}} dx$ is not convergent

Comment: $\sqrt{1+\ln{x^2}}$ is not defined for all $x \in (0,1)$

Comment: again, I made mistake, i edited that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to bound it.

$f(x,n)$ is decreasing sequence of functions and $\int_0^1f(x,1)dx <+\infty$

Let $g(x,n)=f(x,1)-f(x,n)$

$f(x,n) \to 0 ,\forall x \in (0,1)\Longrightarrow g(x,n) \to f_1(x,n), \forall x \in (0,1)$

Thus $\int_0^1g(x,n)dx \to \int_0^1 f(x,1)dx \Longrightarrow \int_0^1 f(x,n)dx \to 0$

By monotone convergence $

Comment: Why I can define that function $g(x,n)$?

Comment: Because the monotone convergence works for increasing functions

Comment: Yeah, but i need to apply that on function $f(x,n)$, didn't I?

Comment: you will find the limit for the functions you want..because the limit of a constant is a constant..